# Совмещение графика, построенного по точкам, с графиком функции

Tags: python, matplotlib

Есть график изменения величины в зависимости от времени. Время изменяется линейно. На него нужно наложить график функции так, чтобы ноль этой функции располагался в определенный день на определенном уровне.
[Датасет](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-0-OjNYZGZCJRy_Y2uiKAS0xYJQgDkEi/view?usp=sharing) actual_df изменения величины от времени имеет вид

```
Date                Close
2020-10-26 00:00:00 74.645
2020-10-26 04:00:00 74.593
2020-10-26 08:00:00 74.831
2020-10-26 12:00:00 74.788
2020-10-26 16:00:00 74.661
2020-10-26 20:00:00 74.615
2020-10-27 00:00:00 74.631
2020-10-27 04:00:00 74.709
2020-10-27 08:00:00 74.514
2020-10-27 12:00:00 74.544
```

этот график строится без проблем кодом

```
plt.plot(actual_df)
```

График функции сам по себе также без проблем строится кодом

```
f = (x-4)**2
plot(f)
```

Как совместить эти два графика таким образом, чтобы нижняя точка графика функции находилась, например, в точке (2020-10-27 04:00:00 71.25)?

Comment: если время меняется линейно, считайте кол-во точек первого графика, вычисляете индекс вашего нуля втрой функции и задавайте правильный диапазон значений для второй функции. Например, всего у вас 5 точек, и вы хотите 0 в второй. Тогда диапазон второго графика от -step до 4 step. Если не линейно - чуть сложнее, но примерно также

Comment: @splash58 Сама идея ясна, но я не понимаю, как ее реализовывать.

Comment: А что вы в качестве `x` в функцию передаёте вообще?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как-то вот так, хотя с виду какая-то ерунда получается, возможно по `x` должны быть дни, например? График же слишком резкий. Ну и подписи по `x` надо прореживать, они сливаются.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

df = pd.read_csv('Example.csv', index_col=0)

plt.figure(figsize=(20,10));
plt.plot(df);

min_x = np.where(df.index == '2020-10-27 04:00:00')[0][0]
min_y = 71.25
x_start = 3
x_end = 12

x = np.arange(x_start, x_end)
f = (x-min_x)**2 + min_y
plt.plot(df.index[x_start:x_end],f);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]